# undefined constant CURLOPT_GET - assumed 'CURLOPT_GET'

Tags: php, curl

I am building my first ever project from scratch on a lamp stack. I decided to try out the slim api framework. Below you can see i start building a helper function for my api. However I am getting this

error: undefined constant CURLOPT_GET - assumed 'CURLOPT_GET'

and then this

error: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

```
// Main Gospel Blocks API Call Function
Function gbCall($gbRoute) {
        // JSON Headers
  $gblCallHeaders[] = "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8";

    // Call the API
    $gblCall = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($gblCall, CURLOPT_URL, $GLOBALS['gbApiUrl'] . $gbRoute);
    curl_setopt($gblCall, CURLOPT_GET, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($gblCall, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($gblCall, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $gblCallHeaders);

    // Get the response
    $response = curl_exec($gblCall);

    // Close cURL connection
    curl_close($gblCall);

    // Decode the response (Transform it to an Array)
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    // Return response
    return $response;
}
```

The api I am hitting is just json encoded objects, not quite sure why this isn't returning the json...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` though I am not sure if it serves your purpose.

[More detail can be found here](http://www.hacksparrow.com/php-curlopt_get-does-not-exist.html)

Comment: Yup that definitely fixed it.

Comment: This is NOT the solution. From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php `CURLOPT_HTTPGET - true to reset the HTTP request method to GET. Since GET is the default, this is only necessary if the request method has been changed.` So the solution is to omit an option to set the request method.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like `CURLOPT_GET` in the options for `cURL` that's why that error occured. Take a look at [CURL options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score 2):

It happens when `phpxxx-curl` was not installed in your machine

Answer (score 0):

```
For the GET Request in the Curl



    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "URL");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Key: Value";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close ($ch);
```